# builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toString'

Tags: python, mysql, linux, qt, pyqt4

I'm a bit of a noob and I've been following a tutorial to create a basic app with PyQt/Python to query a MySql database. Here is the code:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSql

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtSql import *


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QTextBrowser()

# DB type, host, user, password...
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setDatabaseName("microphones")
db.setUserName("root")
db.setPassword("")
ok = db.open()

# True if connected
if ok:
    w.insertHtml('Connected to MySQL<br />')
else:
    w.insertHtml('ERROR connecting to MySQL<br />')

# do a query "on" a DB connection
query = QSqlQuery(db)
if query.exec_("SHOW TABLES"):
    w.insertHtml('<br />')
    while query.next():
        table = query.value(0).toString()
        w.insertHtml('%s<br />' % table)

    w.insertHtml('<br />')
    w.insertHtml('TOTAL %s TABLES' % query.size())

w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the table 'ebay_microphones' in the database 'microphones':

```
ID,product_name,item_number,price
1,"AKG C14",564564564,32
2,"Samsung ",454564545,99
3,"Shure ",564687784,80
```

As far as I'm aware the code is supposed to display the tables in the database, but I'm getting the error `builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toString'`

Could anyone point me in the right direction, why am I getting this error?
Thanks

Comment: `table = query.value(0).toString()` this line should be - `table = str(query.value(0))`

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast response, that's worked! Do you think the guy that wrote the original article was using older syntax from a previous version or just erroneous?

Comment: That's not an older syntax. Just erroneous.

Comment: @bms9nmh. The tutorial you are using is for PyQ4 and Python2, which will use older syntax that is now obsolete. If you can, I would strongly recommend that you switch to using PyQt5 with Python3. Qt4 is no longer officially supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line - `table = query.value(0).toString()` to this -  `table = query.value(0)`

Comment: Since the traceback clearly shows the retun value is a `str`, there is no point in attempting to re-convert it with `str()`. Also, it is wrong to say there is no `toString()`. When using PyQt4 with Python2, `query.value(0)` will return a `QVariant`, which *does* have that method. But when using PyQt4 with Python3, the conversion of Qt classes such as `QString` and `QVariant` is done automatically. The OP is obviously following an old tutorial written for Python2, but is actually using Python3 themselves.

Comment: @ekhumoro ok.Thanks. Edited my answer.